# pass argument to string in Navigate Tag React router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know how to use Navigate in React router v6.
I'm trying to redirect to loggedPath if user is true.
But i don't know syntax to pass *loggedPath* argument to <Navigate to = `${loggedPath}` />

```
import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";


export function IsUserRedirect({ user, loggedPath, children, ...rest }){
    return (
       <Route
        {...rest}
        element ={ !user ? children : user && <Navigate to = `${loggedIath}` /> }
         />
    )}
```

and this is Error message

- Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted
  JSX text
- '{' expected.
- Expression expected.
- Unterminated regular expression literal.
- Declaration or statement expected.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap it in {} when you use ``